# how can i request the location

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, geolocation, android-jetpack-compose

Why do I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMzuW.png) error when asking for the location in this code?

I'm trying to ask for the location to show it but I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)


        setContent {
            MapsTestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    val callbacklocation = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {location: Location? ->
                        location.let {
                            location?.latitude;
                            location?.longitude
                        }
                    }

                    val locationUser=LatLng(callbacklocation.result.latitude,callbacklocation.result.longitude)

                    ShowLastLocation(locationUser)


                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Composable
    fun ShowLastLocation(location: LatLng) {
        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
                    location, 10f
                )
            }
        ) {
            Marker(
                state = MarkerState(
                    position = location
                ),
            )
        }
    }

}
```

I want to be able to request the last location to show it with the google maps API

Comment: https://medium.com/@daniel.atitienei/get-current-user-location-in-jetpack-compose-using-clean-architecture-android-6683abca66c9. using dependency injection and viewmodel

Answer (score 2):

You're breaking the rule of creating side effects in a Composable. Your code will attach another listener on every re-composition, which will be very wasteful and is a memory leak. Side effects must be done only through one of [the official side effect-related functions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) (or something built out of them) so they won't run on every re-composition and you can do memory cleanup appropriately.

The reason it's not working is that getting a location is asynchronous, so the result comes some time in the future. You can't use it immediately. (You can spot asynchronous functions because they usually take callbacks/listeners as arguments. A callback/listener is called in the future when the result is ready.)

However, Google provides a synchronous extension suspend function for their Tasks, called `await()` that can be used in coroutines. This is simpler because it will take care of cleanup, but you will need to use `try`/`catch` to safely handle the possibility of failure.

So in this case, I think `produceState` is the best option. You can use it for creating state and inside its lambda, you can call suspend functions.

State needs a starting value so your composition knows what to do before it's ready. It could be as simple as showing nothing. But you could choose to show a progress bar or a message that says it's loading, etc.

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
) {

    val locationUser by produceState<Location?>(null) {
        try {
            val location = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.await()
            if (location != null) {
                value = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to retrieve last location. $e")
        }
    }

    if (locationUser == null) {
        // do nothing or show a progress bar, etc.
    } else {
        ShowLastLocation(locationUser)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but doing the location as you put it, I get the locationUser = null

Comment: It will definitely be null at first. You have to wait for it. On occasion it might stay null forever. You should check the location documentation to see how it works. You might need to do location updates instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `await()` to wait for the Task to complete and then access its result

```
      var locationUser by remember { mutableStateOf<LatLng?>(null) }
    
      LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                val location = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.await()
                locationUser = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
}
```